# Custom segue crashing with (second) iPad storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

Using Xcode 7.3 I have added a second storyboard (to my universal app) for iPad layout. All works fine except custom segues. For the Main.storyboard the custom segue works fine but if I run Main~iPad.storyboard (iPad device or iPad simulator) the segue crashes.
Crash report as follows:

```
2016-07-05 11:27:13.900 Quiz Maker[1354:42875] *** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate segueWithDestinationViewController:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UIStoryboardSegueTemplate.m:85
```

2016-07-05 11:27:13.926 Quiz Maker[1354:42875] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not create a segue of class '(null)''

Heres my custom segue code:

```
import UIKit

class CustomRightSegue: UIStoryboardSegue
 {
override func perform()
{


    let firstClassView = self.sourceViewController.view
    let secondClassView = self.destinationViewController.view

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    secondClassView.frame = CGRectMake( screenWidth, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {

        window.insertSubview(secondClassView, aboveSubview: firstClassView)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in

            firstClassView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstClassView.frame, -screenWidth, 0)
            secondClassView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondClassView.frame, -screenWidth, 0)

            }) {(Finished) -> Void in

                self.sourceViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false)

        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Add the custom Segue as a connection between the two ViewControllers in the Storyboard.

There, select an available option for 'Module' in the Attributes Inspector:

[Screenshot of the 'Module' Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRZk5.png)

Comment: Points for the "module" mention.  (Why wouldn't it use the default?!?)